# Querying data across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Table Structure]

How can I write a query to find the car return date for a customer named "Bill"?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
SELECT
    RentalReturnDate
FROM
    rentals
JOIN customers ON rentals.CustomerId = customers.CustomerId
WHERE
    customers.CustomerName = "Bill"
```

Or if Bill is just the first part of the name, you can use `%` as a wildcard and change the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE customers.CustomerName like 'Bill%'`

I'd recommend reading some tutorials ([like this one](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)) to learn more about querying and joins